# Flask app: logging inside a (non-flask-related) class fails

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask app that I wanted to add a cache to for API calls, so I wrote a simple caching class that doesn't know anything about flask, just about the cache data, and managing it. It lives in a separate file that starts:

```
import logging
import time

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class CacheCollection:
```

and uses `logger.debug("xxx")` in various places to let you know what's going on.

That all works fine in standalone test code.

HOWEVER, I would like to create this cache in my flask app, and ideally seed it with data when the application starts up. Since Flask hasn't got a "on startup" event like Django does, I am adding this in the `init_bp()` method of my Blueprint. It needs to be after Flask's config is loaded, since the endpoint and key for the API I'm caching is in that config.

When I do that, I get a warning on the first call to the logger in the cache class:

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

which is true I guess, but I don't see why it's relevant. Does Flask mess with the `logging` config enough to break other modules' logging? Having to create a dependency on current_app.logger in this other module seems perverse (and I don't think it will help).

How *should* I be creating these objects outside of a request? I don't want to use `before_first_request`, since it might take a while to run. Other similar questions on SO seem to be for work unrelated to the application itself, running in another thread or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, Flask apps do not have "on startup" method. But you can easily bypass this problem by using a *Application Factory pattern* as described here: [Application Factories](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/appfactories/). That allows you to execute code after the app is created and before it runs.

---

```
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
```

> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
> To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context(). ([Manually Push a Context](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/appcontext/))

Flask provides an easy solution:

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    with app.app_context():
        init_bp()

    return app
```

*Another solution, it is to use the other pattern to initialize extensions (commonly use). You will have access to the app object from your `init_bp` function.*

```
init_bp(app)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will check into this to avoid my current method (I do already use an application factory), but the other question remains - why does Flask even get involved in my non-flask code? I ran it with the debugger and didn't see any references to Flask in the root logger, for example. I'm not using `current_app.logger`, just `logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Wihtout any reproductible code, it is hard to say. You are doing something that needs the app context, try to find what needs the context, or push it manually.

Comment: I made a minimal app that behaves the same, and in the process realised that actually I'm using json_logging, and it's *that* that is the issue - it was trying to get context information from the current request (which is there isn't one) to create correlation IDs. Updating to latest json_logging resolved it.